# Non-Orthogonal Measurements in Quantum Systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, polarization, quantum-measurements

If we aim to transmit some information using the polarization of photons, lets suppose horizontally polarized = |0> and vertically polarized = |1>. We can decode this information at the receiver either by using polarized beam-splitters or a polarization sheet. Same goes for diagonally polarized photons for |+> and |->.

I am confused if we can perform parallel measurements if the states are non-orthogonal, i.e. if the transmitter can transmit |0>,|1>,|+> or |-> (single photon), is it possible to measure which state was sent at the receiver? Are there some beam-splitters or some other thing that can perform such measurements? If so, why do we have the concept of sequential measurements?